# Does bootstrap have builtin padding and margin classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding

Does Bootstrap have built-in padding and margin classes like `pad-10`, `mar-left-10` or I have to add my own custom classes? For example, similar to the ones [here](http://seantheme.com/color-admin-v1.8/admin/html/helper_css.html) at padding and margin tabs.

Comment: Not in Bootstrap 3 but in Bootstrap 4. For Bootstrap 3 you need: https://github.com/diqidoq/qcss/blob/master/qcss.spacing.less which Bootstrap has forked/adopted for Bootstrap 4 and xetended (so no new learning curve)

Comment: There was no sass/scss solution so I put this together for BS3: https://gist.github.com/devkinetic/b5770fbd4ccfa73788539fcdc40fccfb

Comment: I can say Bootstrap 3 doesn't have padding and margin classes. If your legacy still uses bootstrap 3, then it's too bad.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 and 5 took over the approach of JASS (formerly QCSS) with utility classes to additional margin padding etc. But still very hard to overview when it affects the rythm and when not. So my recommendation is still JASS (was QCSS before) https://github.com/diqidoq/jass

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There are built in classes, namely:

```
.padding-xs { padding: .25em; }
.padding-sm { padding: .5em; }
.padding-md { padding: 1em; }
.padding-lg { padding: 1.5em; }
.padding-xl { padding: 3em; }

.padding-x-xs { padding: .25em 0; }
.padding-x-sm { padding: .5em 0; }
.padding-x-md { padding: 1em 0; }
.padding-x-lg { padding: 1.5em 0; }
.padding-x-xl { padding: 3em 0; }

.padding-y-xs { padding: 0 .25em; }
.padding-y-sm { padding: 0 .5em; }
.padding-y-md { padding: 0 1em; }
.padding-y-lg { padding: 0 1.5em; }
.padding-y-xl { padding: 0 3em; }

.padding-top-xs { padding-top: .25em; }
.padding-top-sm { padding-top: .5em; }
.padding-top-md { padding-top: 1em; }
.padding-top-lg { padding-top: 1.5em; }
.padding-top-xl { padding-top: 3em; }

.padding-right-xs { padding-right: .25em; }
.padding-right-sm { padding-right: .5em; }
.padding-right-md { padding-right: 1em; }
.padding-right-lg { padding-right: 1.5em; }
.padding-right-xl { padding-right: 3em; }

.padding-bottom-xs { padding-bottom: .25em; }
.padding-bottom-sm { padding-bottom: .5em; }
.padding-bottom-md { padding-bottom: 1em; }
.padding-bottom-lg { padding-bottom: 1.5em; }
.padding-bottom-xl { padding-bottom: 3em; }

.padding-left-xs { padding-left: .25em; }
.padding-left-sm { padding-left: .5em; }
.padding-left-md { padding-left: 1em; }
.padding-left-lg { padding-left: 1.5em; }
.padding-left-xl { padding-left: 3em; }

.margin-xs { margin: .25em; }
.margin-sm { margin: .5em; }
.margin-md { margin: 1em; }
.margin-lg { margin: 1.5em; }
.margin-xl { margin: 3em; }

.margin-x-xs { margin: .25em 0; }
.margin-x-sm { margin: .5em 0; }
.margin-x-md { margin: 1em 0; }
.margin-x-lg { margin: 1.5em 0; }
.margin-x-xl { margin: 3em 0; }

.margin-y-xs { margin: 0 .25em; }
.margin-y-sm { margin: 0 .5em; }
.margin-y-md { margin: 0 1em; }
.margin-y-lg { margin: 0 1.5em; }
.margin-y-xl { margin: 0 3em; }

.margin-top-xs { margin-top: .25em; }
.margin-top-sm { margin-top: .5em; }
.margin-top-md { margin-top: 1em; }
.margin-top-lg { margin-top: 1.5em; }
.margin-top-xl { margin-top: 3em; }

.margin-right-xs { margin-right: .25em; }
.margin-right-sm { margin-right: .5em; }
.margin-right-md { margin-right: 1em; }
.margin-right-lg { margin-right: 1.5em; }
.margin-right-xl { margin-right: 3em; }

.margin-bottom-xs { margin-bottom: .25em; }
.margin-bottom-sm { margin-bottom: .5em; }
.margin-bottom-md { margin-bottom: 1em; }
.margin-bottom-lg { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
.margin-bottom-xl { margin-bottom: 3em; }

.margin-left-xs { margin-left: .25em; }
.margin-left-sm { margin-left: .5em; }
.margin-left-md { margin-left: 1em; }
.margin-left-lg { margin-left: 1.5em; }
.margin-left-xl { margin-left: 3em; }
```

Comment: Are these Bootstrap built-in clases? They don't seem to be for v3.3

Comment: Look here for an add on for Bootstrap 3: https://github.com/diqidoq/qcss/blob/master/qcss.spacing.less - in Bootstrap 4 they smartly adopted this approach.

Comment: @nilsun I try to follow the link you provided but it's broke

Comment: Yes @YousefAltaf that link is broken but you can still visit https://github.com/diqidoq/qcss if you want to have a look at that example :)

Comment: BS3 + SCSS backport of the BS4 spacing utility: https://gist.github.com/devkinetic/b5770fbd4ccfa73788539fcdc40fccfb

Comment: I'm also using bootstrap 3.3.7 and these classes doesn't work

Comment: @YousefAltaf it is JASS now (formerly QCSS) a complete component based utility-first CSS framework whith many of such tools like requested here: https://github.com/diqidoq/jass

Answer (score 53):

Bootstrap has many facility of classes to easily style elements if HTML. It includes a various of padding and margin classes for modification of the appearance of the element.

```
.m-0 { margin:0!important; }
.m-1 { margin:.25rem!important; }
.m-2 { margin:.5rem!important; }
.m-3 { margin:1rem!important; }
.m-4 { margin:1.5rem!important; }
.m-5 { margin:3rem!important; }

.mt-0 { margin-top:0!important; }
.mr-0 { margin-right:0!important; }
.mb-0 { margin-bottom:0!important; }
.ml-0 { margin-left:0!important; }
.mx-0 { margin-left:0 !important;margin-right:0 !important; }
.my-0 { margin-top:0!important;margin-bottom:0!important; }

.mt-1 { margin-top:.25rem!important; }
.mr-1 { margin-right:.25rem!important; }
.mb-1 { margin-bottom:.25rem!important; }
.ml-1 { margin-left:.25rem!important; }
.mx-1 { margin-left:.25rem!important;margin-right:.25rem!important; }
.my-1 { margin-top:.25rem!important;margin-bottom:.25rem!important; }

.mt-2 { margin-top:.5rem!important; }
.mr-2 { margin-right:.5rem!important; }
.mb-2 { margin-bottom:.5rem!important; }
.ml-2 { margin-left:.5rem!important; }
.mx-2 { margin-right:.5rem!important;margin-left:.5rem!important; }
.my-2 { margin-top:.5rem!important;margin-bottom:.5rem!important; }

.mt-3 { margin-top:1rem!important; }
.mr-3 { margin-right:1rem!important; }
.mb-3 { margin-bottom:1rem!important; }
.ml-3 { margin-left:1rem!important; }
.mx-3 { margin-right:1rem!important;margin-left:1rem!important; }
.my-3 { margin-bottom:1rem!important;margin-top:1rem!important; }

.mt-4 { margin-top:1.5rem!important; }
.mr-4 { margin-right:1.5rem!important; }
.mb-4 { margin-bottom:1.5rem!important; }
.ml-4 { margin-left:1.5rem!important; }
.mx-4 { margin-right:1.5rem!important;margin-left:1.5rem!important; }
.my-4 { margin-top:1.5rem!important;margin-bottom:1.5rem!important; }

.mt-5 { margin-top:3rem!important; }
.mr-5 { margin-right:3rem!important; }
.mb-5 { margin-bottom:3rem!important; }
.ml-5 { margin-left:3rem!important; }
.mx-5 { margin-right:3rem!important;margin-left:3rem!important; }
.my-5 { margin-top:3rem!important;margin-bottom:3rem!important; }

.mt-auto { margin-top:auto!important; }
.mr-auto { margin-right:auto!important; }
.mb-auto { margin-bottom:auto!important; }
.ml-auto { margin-left:auto!important; }
.mx-auto { margin-right:auto!important;margin-left:auto!important; }
.my-auto { margin-bottom:auto!important;margin-top:auto!important; }

.p-0 { padding:0!important; }
.p-1 { padding:.25rem!important; }
.p-2 { padding:.5rem!important; }
.p-3 { padding:1rem!important; }
.p-4 { padding:1.5rem!important; }
.p-5 { padding:3rem!important; }

.pt-0 { padding-top:0!important; }
.pr-0 { padding-right:0!important; }
.pb-0 { padding-bottom:0!important; }
.pl-0 { padding-left:0!important; }                             
.px-0 { padding-left:0!important;padding-right:0!important; }
.py-0 { padding-top:0!important;padding-bottom:0!important; }

.pt-1 { padding-top:.25rem!important; }         
.pr-1 { padding-right:.25rem!important; }                       
.pb-1 { padding-bottom:.25rem!important; }      
.pl-1 { padding-left:.25rem!important; }                            
.px-1 { padding-left:.25rem!important;padding-right:.25rem!important; }
.py-1 { padding-top:.25rem!important;padding-bottom:.25rem!important; }

.pt-2 { padding-top:.5rem!important; }                                              
.pr-2 { padding-right:.5rem!important; }                                
.pb-2 { padding-bottom:.5rem!important; }               
.pl-2 { padding-left:.5rem!important; }                                             
.px-2 { padding-right:.5rem!important;padding-left:.5rem!important; }
.py-2 { padding-top:.5rem!important;padding-bottom:.5rem!important; }

.pt-3 { padding-top:1rem!important; }                               
.pr-3 { padding-right:1rem!important; }             
.pb-3 { padding-bottom:1rem!important; }                
.pl-3 { padding-left:1rem!important; }                              
.py-3 { padding-bottom:1rem!important;padding-top:1rem!important; }
.px-3 { padding-right:1rem!important;padding-left:1rem!important; }

.pt-4 { padding-top:1.5rem!important; }                             
.pr-4 { padding-right:1.5rem!important; }               
.pb-4 { padding-bottom:1.5rem!important; }              
.pl-4 { padding-left:1.5rem!important; }                                
.px-4 { padding-right:1.5rem!important;padding-left:1.5rem!important; }
.py-4 { padding-top:1.5rem!important;padding-bottom:1.5rem!important; }

.pt-5 { padding-top:3rem!important; }   
.pr-5 { padding-right:3rem!important; } 
.pb-5 { padding-bottom:3rem!important; }    
.pl-5 { padding-left:3rem!important; }  
.px-5 { padding-right:3rem!important;padding-left:3rem!important; }
.py-5 { padding-top:3rem!important;padding-bottom:3rem!important; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/x47bca1u/

Comment: You're the man. Dropped this into our very old admin scss.

Answer (score 27):

**This is taken from the docs and it works very well.**
[Here is the link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/)

- m - for classes that set margin
- p - for classes that set padding

**Where sides are one of:**

- **t** - for classes that set **margin-top** or **padding-top**
- **b** - for classes that set **margin-bottom** or **padding-bottom**
- **l** - for classes that set **margin-left** or **padding-left**
- **r** - for classes that set **margin-right** or **padding-right**

if you want to give margin to the left use **ml-x** where x stands for [1,2,3,4,5]

same for padding

example be like

```
<div class = "mt-5"></div>
<div class = "pt-5"></div>
```

Use only **p-x** or **m-x** for getting padding and margin of x from all sides.

Comment: Here is an error: `margin to the left use mt-x` should be `ml-x`.

Answer (score 26):

Bootstrap 4 has a new notation for margin and padding classes. Refer to [Bootstrap 4.0 Documentation - Spacing](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

From the documentation:

> **Notation**
>
> Spacing utilities that apply to all breakpoints, from `xs` to `xl`, have
>   no breakpoint abbreviation in them. This is because those classes are
>   applied from `min-width: 0` and up, and thus are not bound by a media
>   query. The remaining breakpoints, however, do include a breakpoint
>   abbreviation.
>
> The classes are named using the format `{property}{sides}-{size}` for `xs`
>   and `{property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size}` for `sm`, `md`, `lg`, and `xl`.
>
> **Examples**
>
> `.mt-0 { margin-top: 0 !important; }`
>
> `.p-3 { padding: $spacer !important; }`

Comment: Which they have smartly forked/adopted from the Drupal developer diqidoq https://github.com/diqidoq/qcss/blob/master/qcss.spacing.less ;-)

Answer (score 15):

I'm adding this code to my Bootstrap3.3 project with the same grid columns breakpoints, based with the @guest answer. Before I have used the Bootstrap 4 padding and margins helper it seens to be a good choice.

```
/*Margin and Padding helpers*/
/*xs*/
.p-xs { padding: .25em; }
.p-x-xs { padding: 0 .25em; }
.p-y-xs { padding: .25em 0 ; }
.p-t-xs { padding-top: .25em; }
.p-r-xs { padding-right: .25em; }
.p-b-xs { padding-bottom: .25em; }
.p-l-xs { padding-left: .25em; }
.m-xs { margin: .25em; }
.m-x-xs { margin: 0 .25em; }
.m-y-xs { margin: .25em 0 ; }
.m-r-xs { margin-right: .25em; }
.m-l-xs { margin-left: .25em; }
.m-t-xs { margin-top: .25em; }
.m-b-xs { margin-bottom: .25em; }
/*sm*/
@media (min-width:768px){
/*sm*/
.p-sm { padding: .5em; }
.p-x-sm { padding: 0 .5em; }
.p-y-sm { padding: .5em 0 ; }
.p-t-sm { padding-top: .5em; }
.p-r-sm { padding-right: .5em; }
.p-b-sm { padding-bottom: .5em; }
.p-l-sm { padding-left: .5em; }
.m-sm { margin: .5em; }
.m-x-sm { margin: 0 .5em; }
.m-y-sm { margin: .5em 0 ; }
.m-t-sm { margin-top: .5em; }
.m-r-sm { margin-right: .5em; }
.m-b-sm { margin-bottom: .5em; }
.m-l-sm { margin-left: .5em; }
}

/*md*/
@media (min-width: 992px){
.p-md { padding: 1em; }
.p-x-md { padding: 0 1em; }
.p-y-md { padding: 1em 0; }
.p-t-md { padding-top: 1em; }
.p-r-md { padding-right: 1em; }
.p-b-md { padding-bottom: 1em; }
.p-l-md { padding-left: 1em; }
.m-md { margin: 1em; }
.m-x-md { margin: 0 1em; }
.m-y-md { margin: 1em 0 ; }
.m-t-md { margin-top: 1em; }
.m-r-md { margin-right: 1em; }
.m-b-md { margin-bottom: 1em; }
.m-l-md { margin-left: 1em; }
}

/*lg*/
@media (min-width: 1200px){
.p-lg { padding: 1.5em; }
.p-x-lg { padding: 0 1.5em; }
.p-y-lg { padding: 1.5em 0; }
.p-t-lg { padding-top: 1.5em; }
.p-r-lg { padding-right: 1.5em; }
.p-b-lg { padding-bottom: 1.5em; }
.p-l-lg { padding-left: 1.5em; }
.m-lg { margin: 1.5em; }
.m-x-lg { margin: 0 1.5em; }
.m-y-lg { margin: 1.5em 0; }
.m-t-lg { margin-top: 1.5em; }
.m-r-lg { margin-right: 1.5em; }
.m-b-lg { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
.m-l-lg { margin-left: 1.5em; }
}
/*xl*/
.p-xl { padding: 3em; }
.p-x-xl { padding: 0 3em; }
.p-y-xl { padding: 3em 0 ; }
.p-t-xl { padding-top: 3em; }
.p-r-xl { padding-right: 3em; }
.p-b-xl { padding-bottom: 3em; }
.p-l-xl { padding-left: 3em; }
.m-xl { margin: 3em; }
.m-x-xl { margin: 0 3em; }
.m-y-xl { margin: 3em 0; }
.m-t-xl { margin-top: 3em; }
.m-r-xl { margin-right: 3em; }
.m-b-xl { margin-bottom: 3em; }
.m-l-xl { margin-left: 3em; }``
```

Comment: Refer to @Surya R Praveen's answer for a better representation of Bootstrap 4+ and an easier future transition to actual Bootstrap.

Answer (score 10):

For bootstrap 4 we have new classes named with following notation

```
m - for classes that set margin
p - for classes that set padding
```

Specify Top, bottom,left, right, left & right, top & bottom using below letters

```
t - for classes that set margin-top (mt) or padding-top (pt)
b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left
r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right
x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
```

Specify size using following numbers

```
0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
```

Actual Code from bootstrap 4 css file

```
.mt-0 {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.ml-1 {
  margin-left: ($spacer * .25) !important;
}

.px-2 {
  padding-left: ($spacer * .5) !important;
  padding-right: ($spacer * .5) !important;
}

.p-3 {
  padding: $spacer !important;
}
```

**Usage**

So when you need some padding left just add any class from `pl-0` to `pl-5` based on your need

If you need margin on top just add any class from `mt-0` to `mt-5` based on your need

```
<div class="col-sm-6 mt-5"> this div will have margin top added </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 pl-5"> this div will have padding left added </div>
```

[Bootstrap 4 CDN](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Answer (score 10):

Bootstrap 5 has changed the `ml,mr,pl,pr` classes, which no longer work if you're upgrading from a lower version.
The `l` and `r` have now been replaced with `s`(...which is confusing) and `e`(east?) respectively.

From bootstrap website:

**Where property is one of:**

- m - for classes that set margin
- p - for classes that set padding

**Where sides is one of:**

- t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
- b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
- s - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left in LTR, margin-right or padding-right in RTL
- e - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right in LTR, margin-left or padding-left in RTL
- x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
- y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
  blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element
  Where size is one of:

0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
auto - for classes that set the margin to auto
(You can add more sizes by adding entries to the $spacers Sass map variable.)

Comment: Was looking for same explanation. To make sense, I've convinced myself it's s(tart) and e(nd) akin justifying content using flex

Comment: @stubben I googled why the new left and right classes had been renamed and this is probably the only explanation.  Such a dumb thing to do when L and R were perfectly descriptive of the property being manipulated, that being margin-left and margin-right

Comment: Good update - `bootstrap5`, i.e. 5.2 is the current version. Can you format your answer? BTW `s` is start and `e` is end which was (l)eft and (r)ight.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're asking about is how to create responsive spacing between `rows` or `col-xx-xx` classes.

You can definitely do this with the `col-xx-offset-xx` class:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
</div>

<div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-1">
</div>
```

As for adding `margin` or `padding` directly to elements, there are some simple ways to do this depending on your element. You can use `btn-lg` or `label-lg` or `well-lg`. If you're ever wondering, how can i give this alittle padding. Try adding the primary `class name` + `lg` or `sm` or `md` depending on your size needs:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Big Button w/ Display: Block</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap versions before 4 and 5 do not define `ml`, `mr`, `pl`, and `pr`.

Bootstrap versions 4 and 5 define the classes of `ml`, `mr`, `pl`, and `pr`.

**For example:**

```
mr--1
ml--1
pr--1
pl--1
```

Comment: There is nothing new in this answer that is not in already given ones

Comment: This is wrong, [bootstrap 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65545028/1705829) has changed, see [original doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give an example which I tried by understanding above documentation and works correctly.
If you wish to apply 25% padding on left and right sides medium screen size then please use px-md-1.
It works as desired and can similarly follow for other screen sizes. :)

Answer (score 0):

These spacing notations are quite effective in custom changes. You can also use negative values there too. [Official](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/)

Though we can use them whenever we want. [Bootstrap Spacing](https://www.tutorialmines.net/bootstrap-spacing/)

Comment: How does your answer add to other answers which are detailed? Please dont answer if it dosen't add anything to the question. Thanks

Comment: Negative values!