# 2 left align divs poses problem when minimized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="row show-grid">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="pull-left">Start Date Time</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="pull-left">@(item.StartDateTime.ToClientDateTime(tz))</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I am finding is that on my laptop, it shows fine as below:

[image]

When I minimize my screen, it shows as follows:

[image]

Is there a way to gave some gap between Start Date Time and the date/time so they are they are not squished together.

Comment: why don't you add margin to the start date time? I believe you can do this in bootstrap with `mr-3` class. So it would be `<div class="pull-left mr-3">Start Date Time</div>`

Comment: @coops Isn't mr-3 in bootstrap 4?

Comment: ah you're right @Nate Pet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does bootstrap have builtin padding and margin classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233489/does-bootstrap-have-builtin-padding-and-margin-classes)